# Equivalent of json.dump that can be used for specified excel cells with Python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I was using JSON files in order to store data that I was working with but realised that JSON files can't be appended and then read from if there's more than one record.

This has lead to me needing to change how I store and read the data, with Excel being most likely the best option.

I used to have the following code that would put my data into a JSON file:

```
for i in range(len(driver.window_handles)):
    with open("file%s.json" % (i + 1), "w") as outfile:                                 
        json.dump([{"dataHeading1": data1, "dataHeading2": data2, "dataHeading3": data3, outfile)
```

I've installed openpyxl and pandas, however I think the latter is very heavy and most likely not needed for something like the simple task I'm trying to do.

Does anyone know if there is another framework that would be able to put the above data in one go into an excel sheet, for example in the cells "A2":"B22", if it can be done with openpyxl or otherwise?

Comment: Use a database, it's the sort of thing they're designed for.

Comment: I completely agree with Charlie, but if you're looking for something lighter and won't be using it in production code, you could use a CSV file and open it in Excel

Comment: I won't be using so much data that a database is necessary, or would you stand by that suggestion even with a small amount of data?